# curved backdrop looks shows a sharp line

Tags: rendering, cycles-render-engine, light, shadows

Could you help me to identify the problem of shadow on the background as shown in the picture? I don't know the reason why the shadows separate like this, but on the real time rendering I have a nice gradient.

[image]

It looks like this [image]

Comment: Could be quite a few things .. difficult to have a clue without more information about the nature of the background - its geometry? Modifiers? Any settings different for Viewport/Render?

Comment: Make giant flat plane. I think it should do the trick.